# how to make full text combination filter in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I tried to make angularjs full text search like in this plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/PwcteF6WAtuAOj3ZDKLe?p=preview

I've tried many combination but none works..

e.g I want to search cross column like 'alex big-mary' or 'alex 800' or 'mary big' but not works
alex 555 works because 555 exist right after alex word

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/7skYY6aeVAtQOTA7GTuV?p=preview is what you need?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I dont know any built-in filter that would perform an OR-like search. You can define your own filter that would fit your needs:

```
angular.module('App', []).filter('search', function($filter){
   return function(items, text){
      if (!text || text.length === 0)
        return items;

      // split search text on space
      var searchTerms = text.split(' ');

      // search for single terms.
      // this reduces the item list step by step
      searchTerms.forEach(function(term) {
        if (term && term.length)
          items = $filter('filter')(items, term);
      });

      return items
   };
});
```

See this code in action using this Plunkr:  [simple OR search filter](http://plnkr.co/edit/62bMPl08MHG01STL0L7O)

Comment: that works like our user want, it's help ful when we search liek alex that live in exact city...thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a custom filter that will take your data and tokenize it on per row basis and only display those rows that match the strings that you enter.

Here are the docs for creating custom filters:

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.templates.filters.creating_filters